# Как изменить название ключа acf wordpress?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, wordpress-плагины, acf

Есть связка сайт на `wordpress`, [плагин произвольных полей acf](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) и бд `mysql`
Планирую заменить некоторые названия **ключей acf** так, чтобы не потерять информацию записанную в этих полях.

[image: название 1]

[Делаю по инструкции](https://wpforthewin.com/update-acf-field-name-without-losing-data/)

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` as m JOIN `wp_posts` as p ON m.post_id = p.ID SET m.meta_key = '_new_field_name' WHERE m.meta_value = 'field_5af0d933478b4' AND p.post_type = 'post'
```

Но, у меня в post_type могут быть post, page, custom post, options page.
В итоге получаю такую историю, что само название ключа изменилось, а связка ключ-значение осталось исходным. Как победить?

[image: название 2]